# ngmodelchange fires first time itself

Tags: angular

```
<select [(ngModel)]="projectID" id="projectSelect" class="form-control" name="projectSelect" (ngModelChange)="paginationNavigation('project');">
    <option value="0" selected>All Projects</option>
    <option *ngFor="let project of projectWorkobject" value="{{project.id}}">
        {{project.projectName}}(ID:{{project.id}})
    </option>
</select>
```

this calls paginationnavigation function first time itself, I want it to be run only after user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

The `ngModelChange` will fire whenever `ngModel` is changed.  And `ngModel` is bound to a variable called `projectID`.  So, the initial call you are seeing is probably related to the default 'draw' of the screen containing this form element.  I don't think there is going to be any way you can prevent that.

You might be able to work around that by creating an initialized variable and setting it in the `ngAfterContentInit()` method.

Conceptually something like this:

```
initialized = false;
paginationNavigation(arg) {
  if (this.initialized){
      // do my stuff
  }
  // else do nothing
}

ngAfterContentInit() {
  this.initialized = true;
}
```